# Actualizar datos de una tabla con input

Tags: php, mysql

tengo una pagina llamada categories, en donde hay una lista de categorías que el usuario va creando, y estas se van agregando a una tabla llamada categories que se compone únicamente de dos columnas (id y name),  lo que quisiera hacer es que el usuario pueda actualizar el nombre de las categorías, sin embargo y debido a mi falta de conocimiento en php, no lo he logrado.
desde la página de categorías el usuario tiene un link que lo lleva a la página de actualizar categorías.
este es el link  `echo '<a class="btn btn-primary" href="actualizar-categoria.php?id='.$category['id'].'">Modificar</a>';`.
Y este es el php que tengo en la pagina llamada actualizar-categoria.php es la pagina que tengo para que la categoría sea actualizada.

````
     
     require 'database.php';

     if(!empty($_GET['id'])) 
     {
         $id = checkInput($_GET['id']);
     }
 
    $nameError = $name = "";

    if(!empty($_POST)) 
    {
        $name = checkInput($_POST['name']);
        $isSuccess = true;
       

        
        if(empty($name)) 
        {
            $nameError = 'Este campo no puede estar vacío';
            $isSuccess = false;
        }
        
        else {
           
           
            $db = Database::connect();
            $statement = $db->prepare(" UPDATE categories  set name = ? WHERE id = ?");
            $statement->execute(array($name,$id));
            Database::disconnect();
            header("Location: categorias.php");

        }
    }

    function checkInput($data) 
    {
      $data = trim($data);
      $data = stripslashes($data);
      $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
      return $data;
    }

?>```
````

Comment: ¿Qué comportamiento te da este código?

Comment: Hola, no hace nada , es más no da errores, simplemente no actualiza el nombre de la categoría, otra cosa es que generalmente cuando por ejemplo actualizo otros campos por ejemplo nombre de usuario, generalmente en el campo input aparece el nombre que tiene ese id, pero en este no aparece nada, simplemente no hace nada .

Comment: Te recomendaría que aprendas a depurar tu código, te ahorrarás horas y muchos dolores de cabeza. Cuando algo no funcione, depúralo. En este caso, lo primero que tienes que empezar a depurar son los datos que están llegando, poniendo un `var_dump(_$GET);` al principio del código verás si está llegando algo, qué está llegando y cómo está llegando. Luego, revisa el flujo del programa. Por ejemplo, estás mezclando obtención de datos con `$_GET` y con `$_POST`, los datos llegan por un método, no por dos métodos (supongo que en este caso sería `$_GET`), pues usa `$_GET` en todo.

Comment: Exelente Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado

```
<?php

require 'database.php';

if(!empty($_GET['id'])) 
{
    $id = checkInput($_GET['id']);
}

$name = "";

if(!empty($_POST)) 
{
    $name   = checkInput($_POST['name']);
    $isSuccess  = true;
   
    if(empty($name)) 
    {
        $nameError = 'Este campo no puede estar vacío';
        $isSuccess = false;
    }
    

    else
    {
        $isSuccess = true;

    }
     
    if ($isSuccess ) 
    {
    $db = Database::connect();
    $statement = $db->prepare("UPDATE categories  set name = ? WHERE id = ?");
     $statement->execute(array($name,$id));
    }

        Database::disconnect();
        header("Location: categorias.php");
    }

else 
{
    $db = Database::connect();
    $statement = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE id = ?");
    $statement->execute(array($id));
    $category = $statement->fetch();
    $name  = $category['name'];
    Database::disconnect();
}

function namelExists($pdo, $name) {
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT 1 FROM categories WHERE name=?");
    $stmt->execute([$email]); 
    return $stmt->fetchColumn();
    // found
}
```

?>